# How do I retrieve multiple multi-properties in Gremlin?

Tags: java, gremlin

I have a Person object that I'm writing to a graph like this:

```java
gts.addV(newId).label('Person')
  .property(single, 'name', 'Alice')
  .property(set, 'email', 'alice1@example.invalid')
  .property(set, 'email', 'alice2@example.invalid')
```

Now I want to retrieve contents of the vertex. As documented, `elementMap` doesn't work because it returns just a single property value for multi-properties. I tried `values('name', 'email')`, but that returned all of the properties in a flattened list instead of the nested structure I expected:

```
['Alice', 'alice2@example.invalid', 'alice1@example.invalid']
```

I've tried various combinations of `values`, `project`, and `as/select`, but I always get an empty result, a flat list, or a single value on multi-properties.

How can I query a vertex so that I get something like these results?

```
['Alice', ['alice2@example.invalid', 'alice1@example.invalid']]
```

or

```
[name:'Alice', email:['alice2@example.invalid', 'alice1@example.invalid']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking to return a map of the values you can achieve this using the `valueMap()` [step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#valuemap-step):

`g.V(newId).valueMap('name', 'email')`

which will return:

`[name:[Alice],email:[alice1@example.invalid,alice2@example.invalid]]`

If you want to return just the values you can do that by adding a `select(values)`:

`g.V().valueMap('name', 'email').select(values)`

which returns

`[[Alice],[alice1@example.invalid,alice2@example.invalid]]`

Comment: This may be what I'm looking for. Can you clarify your `select(values)` suggestion? I don't know what identifier `values` is, and `select(__.values())` seems to trigger exceptions.

Comment: The `values` referenced here is part of the `Column.values` enum and tells the traversal to return the value portion or the map.   This could have also been written as `g.V().valueMap('name', 'email').select(Column.values)` 

Here is a link to the documentation on the Column Enum: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Column.html

Comment: Hmm. It appears that `select(Column.values)` doesn't preserve order (in addition to omitting undefined properties), so I'll stick with the map-returning version. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So that is going to return only the values from the map output by the `valueMap()` step.  It should only contain the properties included in that step.  As far as order goes it appears to be retaining them from Gremlin server but TinkerPop in general does not guarantee the order values are return, only that it will return them in the order the server sends it.  If you want to guarantee the order you need to order each row by the keys in the map `g.V().valueMap('name', 'email').order(local).by(select(Column.keys)).select(Column.values)`